# decryption AES256 in C#

Tags: c#, aes

```cs
static byte[] HexToByteArray(string hex)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}

byte[] data = HexToByteArray("004FB8A54E37D642BAB9E26A10242F0D02000000DB7B7425C4EFA00A50FCE2BF38445B5E25ED086E47304A56DD2B3DC85E281291");
       
using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    csp.KeySize = 256;
    csp.BlockSize = 128;
    csp.Key = new byte[32] {
    //    1     9     1     2     7     3     5     5
        0x31, 0x39, 0x31, 0x32, 0x37, 0x33, 0x35, 0x35,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    };
    csp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    csp.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(data, iv, 16);
    csp.IV = iv;

    byte[] decrypted = csp.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 16, data.Length - 16);
    string plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
    MessageBox.Show(plaintext);
    Console.WriteLine(plaintext);
}
```

Here is SQL encrypt:

```
create master key encryption by
    password = '19127355';

--tao certificate
create certificate myCert
    with subject = 'myCert';

create symmetric key PriKey
with algorithm = AES_256
encryption by certificate myCert;

create procedure SP_INS_NHANVIEN
(
    @id varchar(20), 
    @count int,
as
begin
    declare @encL varbinary(max);
    open symmetric key PriKey
    decryption by certificate myCert
    set @encL = encryptbykey(key_guid('PriKey'), convert(varbinary, @count))
    insert into NHANVIEN
    values (@id, @encP2);
end
```

I want to decrypt the value above (AES256). The key is Prikey. But when encrypt in SQL server, it just had 52 bytes, so I can't decrypt in C#. (I still can decrypt it in SQL Server by query command). The error is : 'The input data is not a complete block.'

What can I do to fix this problem? (The result of decryption is 3000000)

Comment: The key isn't 19127355, it's PriKey.

Comment: Passwords are rarely used to encrypt anything directly. They are often put thru a "key derivation function" before being suitable for use as an encryption. I'm not familiar with SQL, but many systems has a list of the real encryption keys, and use the password to encrypt this list. That way you can change the password without re-encrypting all the data. In the end, you need to get the *actual encryption key* if you want to decrypt anything.

Comment: Why don't you just use `decryptbykey` on the SQL side? Also `convert(varbinary, @count)` should be `convert(varbinary(someLength), @count)`

Comment: With your specific `CREATE KEY` command you seem to create a random key, encrypted using a certificate. I don't see you using a password. Secondly, I don't know why you have to specify the `@count`, if that count is wrong then your encryption code seem to cut bytes.

Comment: Database encryption routines are probably the worst out there. The documentation doesn't note the mode of operation used, the algorithm may default to zero padded plaintext, which *might* mean CBC. It is not documented how the IV is handled. Authentication is optional. It basically compasses everything wrong with cryptography today.